# Dificuldade com a função de "find and replace" em javascript para um aplicativo de navegador

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Estou tentando desenvolver uma extensão para o Chrome, e ainda estou nos primeiros passos, e logo no começo já estou empacado. Sei bem pouco de javascript mas tento fazer o que posso pesquisando. Essa extensão é inspirada no [**FoxReplace**](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/foxreplace/) do [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), ou seja, é uma extensão que procura por todas as entradas designadas pelo usuário na página que for e substitui por qualquer outro texto que o usuário colocar.

Achei uma extensão para o Chrome no [github](/questions/tagged/github) e usei ela como referência, mas por ela ser hiper simples (apenas pegar "The Cloud" e substituir por "my butt" -- sim, é bem tosco mesmo), não dá pra seguir muita coisa, além de que o código escrito lá eu ainda não sei interpretar muito bem pra poder colocar o que pretendo.

O que eu já tentei (do zero):

Coloquei:

```
var str = "Texto da substituição";
var res = str.replace(/Será substituído/gim,"Substituirá");
```

Mas não funciona do jeito que queria, porque além de isso só procurar pelo termo dentro de "Texto da substituição", ao invés de todo o documento, ainda por cima precisa de algo pra iniciar a busca pelos termos, que procurei em vários sites, mas tudo que achei foi códigos pra colocar diretamente no HTML da página, na tag `body`, o que eu acho que, se não estou errado, passaria a não ter contato com a extensão, por fazer parte da página e não do aplicativo.

A extensão que eu peguei usa `walk(document.body)` e depois define a função `walk(node)` com a "statement" (não sei como isso é chamado em português) `switch (node.nodeType)`, que pelo que vi, funciona do jeito esperado, mas precisa de várias correções porque falha em várias situações diferentes.

Portanto, eu gostaria que alguém me explicasse o funcionamento do `walk`, do `switch` e dos `case`s do jeito que eles foram usados, e/ou me dizer como fazer isso que eu pretendo de um modo mais apropriado para a minha intenção. 
Essa extensão que peguei, tendo eu editado com o que eu sei, funciona até que bem, o problema são os bugs e umas coisas meio inexplicáveis que acontecem com o código principal dele, que só vou poder, talvez, corrigir, quando entender o conteúdo.

[**Código fonte da extensão de referência**](https://github.com/panicsteve/cloud-to-butt/blob/master/Source/content_script.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estou assumindo que você está familiarizado com a sintaxe de JavaScript, se sabe como um `switch` e `case` funciona. Se estiver enganado, sugiro começar com um tutorial de JavaScript, ou talvez fazer uma pergunta mais específica (tipo: "como funciona o swith no JavaScript?").

No código de exemplo postado, `walk` é uma função recursiva que "visita" um elemento, depois visita todos os seus sub-elementos. Portanto, se seu HTML for algo do tipo:

```html
<body>
    <div id="a">
        <span id="b"></span>
        <span id="c"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        <span id="e"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="f"></div>
</body>
```

Ele vai visitar nessa ordem: `body`, `div#a`, `span#b`, `span#c`, `div#d`, `span#e`, `div#f`. Isso é o que os 3 primeiros `case`s fazem - se o elemento visitado for do tipo "elemento, "documento" ou "fragmento de documento", visite seus filhos. Dessa forma, todo o conteúdo do documento será visitado, como você quer.

Já o outro `case` é para tratar de nós de texto. Um nó de texto é simplesmente o conteúdo textual de um elemento. Por exemplo, os nós de texto do exemplo abaixo:

```html
<span>Este <b>é</b> um texto <i>formatado</i>.</span>
```

são:

- Em `span`: "Este ", " um texto ", "."
- Em `b`: "é"
- Em `i`: "formatado"

Toda vez que um nó de texto é visitado ele chama o `handleText`, que por sua vez pega o conteúdo desse nó (i.e. uma string) e põe na variável `v`. Ele altera a variável `v`, e depois atribuir de volta ao nó de texto.

Espero que isso tenha te ajudado a entender como o exemplo funciona, de modo que você possa adaptá-lo para fazer o que quer. Por exemplo, para fazer a substituição que você quer, basta fazê-lo na variável `v`, em vez de criar uma variável nova (`str`).

```js
v = v.replace(/Será substituído/gim,"Substituirá")
```

Mover os textos "hardcoded" para uma variável, de modo a ficar mas fácil modificá-la:

```js
var de = /Será substituído/gim;
var para = "Substituirá";

...

v = v.replace(de, para);
```

E por fim achar um meio de atribuir valores para essas duas variáveis. Não tenho experiência com extensões do Chrome e portanto não sei se essa é a melhor maneira, mas um jeito seria simplesmente usar [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt):

```js
var de = new RegExp(prompt("Entre com o texto a procurar", "Será substituído"), "gim");
var para = prompt("Entre com o texto a substituir", "Substituirá");

...
```

(O segundo argumento é um valor padrão, que você pode omitir se não quiser um)

---

**Atualização:** normalmente um `iframe` não tem seu conteúdo navegado - em especial se for de um domínio diferente - por razões de segurança. Mas em se tratando de uma extensão do browser, *talvez* isso seja permitido nesse caso. Experimente tratar explicitamente do caso do `iframe`, modificando o primeiro `case` da seguinte forma:

```js
    next = child.nextSibling;
    if ( child.tagName === "iframe" )     // Se for um iframe...
        walk(child.contentDocument.body); // ...acessa o body do seu documento.
    else             // Senão...
        walk(child); // ...percorre normalmente.
    child = next;
```

Comment: Algo que eu não consigo entender é o motivo de esse script não funcionar em `iframe`s, como por exemplo, os comentários do plugin do Facebook. Se o 4° `case` serve para qualquer texto visível da página, por que cargas d'água ele não consegue enxergar o texto dentro do `iframe`?? Já tentei tudo quanto é linha de código voltado aos `iframe`s pra ver se conseguia encontrar os termos dentro dele, mas nada funcionou.

Comment: @BrunoLopes A partir do DOM da página principal, você não consegue acessar o conteúdo dos `iframe`s - em especial de um domínio diferente - por razões de segurança. Sendo uma extensão do browser, talvez ele tenha privilégios adicionais, não sei... Atualizei minha resposta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Para procurar em todo o documento você precisa do conteúdo do corpo.

```
var search = /(Texto\s+da\s+substituição|Outro)/gi;
var replace = 'Substituir por isto';

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body_content = body.innerHTML.replace(search, replace);
body.innerHTML = body_content;
```

Comment: Esse código funcionou, mas só para os textos que estão em forma "crua", simples. Não funciona em `iframe`s, que é a minha principal intenção.